# Modal Window and struts 2 action

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2

I have a requirement of displaying the processing modal popup on click of button in my jsp. On click of submit button it goes to Processing Action which continously check whether the data is available or not meanwhile it should display the progress bar in modal window and once the action returns the data it should automatically close the popup and display the table below the submit button.

Can any please help how to achieve this?

Comment: this is nothing to be with S2 use a simple jquery and you are good to go

Comment: but i have to do with struts action class becoz this processing Action is customized execandwait Interceptor which polls for the data.. so i have to go with struts 2

Comment: it's ok showing model box is client side things and how you display it nothing to do with S2, all you have to handle is to close the model box on getting the result from the action which is quite straight-forward.

Comment: @Quaternion: most of them are moving around file upload ,thinking to work on some example. :)

Comment: can u pls tell me how to close popup on getting the result from the action

Comment: @swingmicro if i am not wrong all you need to hide it based on certain condition. and its hard to say how to close it as there are many ways you can close it

Comment: this is the flow iam looking at search.jsp(search button clk)---> searchaction--->processingAction--->Processing.jsp displaying a processing msg---> once the data is available(or returns success) from searchaction--->auto close this jsp and display search.jsp with data table below search button.. so i want to display this processing.jsp in modal dialog